# using 9-patch imagebutton bigger

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I have a screen with some imageButton, it looks fine in mobiles, but I would like them in tablets.

So, I tried 9-patch, but I dont know how to use the button.9.png.

I create the images for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi, all of them are name.9.dpi

How can I "tell " de app resize depending on the screen size?

This is my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/account_but"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/accountDesc"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/boton_usos" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/alquilar_but"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/alquilarDesc"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/boton_alquilar" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/paradas_but"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/paradasDesc"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/boton_paradas" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/noticias_but"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/noticiasDesc"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/boton_noticias" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/incidencia_but"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/incidenciaDesc"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/boton_incidencia" />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/informacion_but"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/boton_informacion" />


<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/banner_but"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/banner" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) extensively. It will explain what you want to do with your images and different dpi folders.

9-patches are used for stretching mostly, therefore you do not require it to be for different densities. They usually are very small images that will even stretch to take up bigger views' backgrounds and srcs.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand my problem, I have the dpi folders, and work perfect in all density mobiles, but the problem is with tablets, its hdpi, but its a big screen